# Multiple Array Insertion in C# using Foreach statement

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach-loop-container

[image]

```
private void Updated_ModRecFGA()
        {
            try
            {
                DRFGAModifiedRecord TABLE = new DRFGAModifiedRecord();
                foreach (ArrayFunc Row in ArrayFunc.QueryResult)
                {
                    foreach (ArrayFunc Row2 in ArrayFunc.QueryResult1)
                    {
                        TABLE.RecordDocID = Row.FGACol1;
                        TABLE.DRNo = Row.FGACol2;
                        TABLE.DDNum = Row.FGACol3;
                        TABLE.LineNumber = Row.FGACol4;
                        TABLE.Itemnmbr = Row2.updItemCode;
                        TABLE.Itemdesc = Row2.updItemDesc;
                        TABLE.Pallet = Row2.updPallets;
                        TABLE.BagsNo = Row2.updBagsNo;
                        TABLE.TotalLoaded = Row2.updTotalKgs;
                        TABLE.PostStat = Row2.updPostStat;
                        TABLE.ProdCode = Row2.updProdcode;
                        TABLE.VariantCode = Row2.updVariantCode;
                        TABLE.DateModify = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                        TABLE.TimeModify = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        TABLE.UserModify = "Mik";//GlobalvarClass.LogUser;
                        TABLE.ReasonModify = GlobalvarClass.GetModReasOnDR;
                        TABLE.FileType = "New";

                        saveREC(TABLE);
                        gfunc.MsgBox("Saved", 1);
                    }
                }

                ArrayFunc.QueryResult.Clear();
                ArrayFunc.QueryResult1.Clear();
                GlobalvarClass.GetModReasOnDR = string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
        }
```

Is there another proper way to use this kind of code something like this to avoid duplicate? I know it duplicate because of two `foreach` statement

Comment: you could break both `foreach` up into separate methods with the first method returning a bool, and have the `foreach (ArrayFunc Row2 in ArrayFunc.QueryResult1)` method take the bool from the first method.  That's how I'd start breaking both `foreach` statements up.
                    {

Comment: I think that you might need to filter out irrelevant rows for your second collection, and then iterate on what is left.

Comment: thanks ZeroPhase and Tsabo yes its what i did i've break them of then.. i already done it.. i was just thinking if maybe there might be a way of handling two dimensional array on array function for inserting it to sql thanks for the tips together without breaking it.. but it always result on duplicating the data so i do break them off then.. by inserting the datas in a sequence. thanks very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the two using linq. Remember to include `using System.Linq;` in your using clause.

```
var results = ArrayFunc.QueryResult.SelectMany(l1 => ArrayFunc.QueryResult1, (l1, l2) => 
  new DRFGAModifiedRecord
  {
        RecordDocID = l1.FGACol1,
        DRNo = l1.FGACol2,
        DDNum = l1.FGACol3,
        LineNumber = l1.FGACol4,
        Itemnmbr = l2.updItemCode,
        Itemdesc = l2.updItemDesc,
        Pallet = l2.updPallets,
        BagsNo = l2.updBagsNo,
        TotalLoaded = l2.updTotalKgs,
        PostStat = l2.updPostStat,
        ProdCode = l2.updProdcode,
        VariantCode = l2.updVariantCode,
        DateModify = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
        TimeModify = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
        UserModify = "Mik",//GlobalvarClass.LogUser
        ReasonModify = GlobalvarClass.GetModReasOnDR,
        FileType = "New"
  }).ToList();

foreach (row in results)
{
  saveREC(row);
  gfunc.MsgBox("Saved", 1);
}
```

Alternatively you can do it with a query expression:

```
var result = (from l1 in ArrayFunc.QueryResult
             from l2 in ArrayFunc.QueryResult1       
             select new DRFGAModifiedRecord { RecordDocID = l1.FGACol1 ... }).ToList();
```

Comment: pleasure Mik... if the answer is sufficient, please mark your questioned as answered.